# substring_index in replace mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

lets say i have sentence like this

```
   id    sentence
    1. I LOVE ORANGE 300G, and i want that Orange 300G
    2. I HATE STRAWBERRY 500G, and i want that Strawberry 500G
    3. i love the orange 300G (with that big), and i want that orange 300G (with that big)
```

i want remove the last index for each sentence so the expected results should be like this

```
I LOVE ORANGE 300G, and i want that Orange
I HATE STRAWBERRY 500G, and i want that Strawberry
i love the orange 300G (with that big), and i want that orange (with that big)
```

i've tried with this

```
SELECT REPLACE(mytable.sentence, substring_index(mytable.sentence, '', -1), '') AS meta_keywords2 FROM mytable
```

but since the last index are always same with the other in 1 sentence the result be like this :

```
I LOVE ORANGE, and i want that Orange
I HATE STRAWBERRY, and i want that Strawberry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(mytable.sentence, 1, LENGTH(mytable.sentence)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mytable.sentence, ' ', -1))) AS meta_keywords2 
FROM mytable;
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=06b511ac145e0659d315e5e3733b7080)

1. Get the `LENGTH()` of the last word in sentence that you're extracting.
2. Get the total `LENGTH()` of `sentence`.
3. Use `SUBSTRING()` on `sentence` with start position `1` and extract total characters difference between the total length and last word length.

Comment: thankyou very much sir, but when i check it, there's another cases, i will edited it, i will keep mark this answer as an answer but please can you help me with new cases? a little cases

Comment: please check my newest edit sir, thankyou very much

Comment: Will the sentence include any number apart from the last `300G` or `500G`? For example, will you have a sentence that look like this = `I LOVE THAT 1 ORANGE 300G, and i want that 1 Orange 300G`?

Comment: Quite complicated though https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a508be21bc7b4dde73bc18d289d507f0

Comment: Yes, my purpose is to remove unit weight such as 200G or 400G or 500G, etc.

Comment: Is that the only variation of `sentence` data in your table? If there's more, can you post all the variation into your question? thanks